# MVC Passing Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a MVC newcomer. I would like to pass the parameter adminNo, but it's always null. I have been stuck with this problem for the past few days.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult PledgeForm(string adminNo)
{
    var result = new StudentJournalQuery().GetStudentInfo(adminNo);
    return View(result);
}
```

**RouteConfig**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default1",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{adminno}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", adminno = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

**ActionMethod**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("PledgeForm", "ManageSipStudentJournal", new {adminNo = @Model.adminNo, area= string.Empty})">View Pledge Form</a>
```

**SQL Query** Here is the SQL query

```
public StudentJournalSummary GetJournalSummary(string adminNo)
{
    var StudentJournalSummary = new StudentJournalSummary();
    const string _CountSql =
        @"select count(sjd.WeekNo) TotalWeek, sum(sj.TotalDaysRecord) TotalDaysRecord, count(case sjd.JournalStatusCode when  'D' then 1 else null end) PendingComplete from StudentJournalDate sjd left outer join 
        (select sj.WeekNo, 
         case when RTRIM(sj.Day1Journal) = '' or sj.Day1Journal is null then 0 else 1 end +
         case when RTRIM(sj.Day2Journal) = '' or sj.Day2Journal is null then 0 else 1 end +
         case when RTRIM(sj.Day3Journal) = '' or sj.Day3Journal is null then 0 else 1 end +
         case when RTRIM(sj.Day4Journal) = '' or sj.Day4Journal is null then 0 else 1 end +
         case when RTRIM(sj.Day5Journal) = '' or sj.Day5Journal is null then 0 else 1 end +
         case when RTRIM(sj.Day6Journal) = '' or sj.Day6Journal is null then 0 else 1 end +
         case when RTRIM(sj.Day7Journal) = '' or sj.Day7Journal is null then 0 else 1 end as TotalDaysRecord 
         from StudentJournal sj ) as sj  on sjd.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo";

    using (var connection = Db.SqlServer())
    {
        StudentJournalSummary = connection
         .Query<StudentJournalSummary>(_CountSql, new { adminNo }).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return StudentJournalSummary;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's typo. `adminno` vs `adminNo`

Comment: I change it to adminNo. It is still null.

Comment: Is `Model.adminNo` a non null value ?

Comment: Have you set a field `adminNo` bound to your model class on view? Simple `Html.HiddenFor(model => model.adminNo)` or `Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.adminNo)` may solve your null value problem, or use ajax call to pass model data into the controller action method.

Comment: Do you another routeconfig? Make sure that the most specific configuration should be placed on top for it to effect. ktnxbye

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to remove @ in Model.adminNo it does not need becuase already define in @Url.Action

```
<a href="@Url.Action("PledgeForm", "ManageSipStudentJournal", new {adminNo = Model.adminNo, area= string.Empty})">View Pledge Form</a>
```